# create a draggable menu in Django and a custom CMS

Tags: jquery, django

I am trying to create a draggable menu in a custom CMS and admin panel for a Django project.
I wonder if there is any way to get the new sort of blocks and save it in the database.

as an explanation, this is the first order:
[image]

and it is a draggable sort of block using JQuery. for example the second order of the blocks after dragging some of them:
[image]

It is ok to show the base order of blocks to admins. But how can I get the new sort in `views.py` after the admin has changed the sort?

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-8 column">
              <div class="block">
                <div class="block-title">
                  <h2>Block #1</h2>
                </div>
                <p>...</p>
              </div>

              <div class="block">
                <div class="block-title">
                  <h2>Block #2</h2>
                </div>
                <p>...</p>
              </div>
            </div>

<!-- Other Blocks -->
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
var UiDraggable = function() {

    return {
        init: function() {
            $('.draggable-blocks').sortable({
                connectWith: '.block',
                items: '.block',
                opacity: 0.75,
                handle: '.block-title',
                placeholder: 'draggable-placeholder',
                tolerance: 'pointer',
                start: function(e, ui){
                    ui.placeholder.css('height', ui.item.outerHeight());
                }
            });
        }
    };
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

We just did something similar for a project where you can rank alternatives by ordering them, using drag and drop. We used Django's [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/formsets/) and the library [SortableJS/Sortable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable).

The main concept in our implementation is this:
A form contains all the blocks and each block contains an hidden input field. The hidden input has an unique id and name (both related to the block/alternative) and a value that represents the position of the block in the rank. Then, when a block is moved, some javascript code updates all the values of the hidden fields, to reflect the new positions. At the bottom of the page there's a botton to submit the form, and the view that receives the form uses the names and the values of the hidden input to find the new position of each block.

These are some snippets of our code, they should be of some help to give you an idea of how we solved this problem. I tried to remove all the unnecessary parts. Since we used Formsets, the HTML may not be very clear.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.management_form }}
   <div>
       <ol class="list-group list-group-numbered" id="items">
       {% for f in form %}
           <li>
               <div>
                   {{ f.order.label }}
                   {{ f.order }}
               </div>
           </li>
       {% endfor %}
       </ol>
   </div>

   {% include "polls/includes/alert-non-modify.html"%}

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script src="{% static 'js/plugins/Sortable.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const alternatives = document.getElementById('items');

    // Set the index of each item
    const setIndex = arr => arr.forEach((item, index) => {
        const input = item.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        input.value = index + 1;
    })

    // Set the index of each item on load
    setIndex([...alternatives.children])
    Sortable.create(alternatives, {
        animation: 150,
        ghostClass: 'blue-background-class',
        chosenClass: 'blue-background-class',
        dragClass: 'blue-background-class',

        onEnd: (/**Event*/evt) => {
            setIndex([...alternatives.children])
        },
    });
</script>
```

This is the HTML generated in the front end, so you can see what the code generated by our Django template looks like. Notice that there's a lot of stuff specific to our application.

```html
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="...">
    <input type="hidden" name="shultzeopinionjudgement_set-TOTAL_FORMS" value="5" id="id_shultzeopinionjudgement_set-TOTAL_FORMS"><input type="hidden" name="shultzeopinionjudgement_set-INITIAL_FORMS" value="0" id="id_shultzeopinionjudgement_set-INITIAL_FORMS"><input type="hidden" name="shultzeopinionjudgement_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS" value="5" id="id_shultzeopinionjudgement_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS"><input type="hidden" name="shultzeopinionjudgement_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS" value="5" id="id_shultzeopinionjudgement_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <ol class="list-group list-group-numbered gap-2" id="items">
            
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start p-4 border border-primary">
                    <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                        Alternativa uno
                        <input type="hidden" name="shultzeopinionjudgement_set-0-order" id="id_shultzeopinionjudgement_set-0-order" value="1">
                    </div>
                </li>
            
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start p-4 border border-primary">
                    <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                        Alternativa due
                        <input type="hidden" name="shultzeopinionjudgement_set-1-order" id="id_shultzeopinionjudgement_set-1-order" value="2">
                    </div>
                </li>
            
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start p-4 border border-primary">
                    <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                        Alternativa tre
                        <input type="hidden" name="shultzeopinionjudgement_set-2-order" id="id_shultzeopinionjudgement_set-2-order" value="3">
                    </div>
                </li>
            
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start p-4 border border-primary">
                    <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                        Alternativa quattro
                        <input type="hidden" name="shultzeopinionjudgement_set-3-order" id="id_shultzeopinionjudgement_set-3-order" value="4">
                    </div>
                </li>
            
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start p-4 border border-primary">
                    <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                        Alternativa cinque
                        <input type="hidden" name="shultzeopinionjudgement_set-4-order" id="id_shultzeopinionjudgement_set-4-order" value="5">
                    </div>
                </li>
            
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>

    


    
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salva</button>
    </div>
</form>
```